# How to validate User name Password using JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to build a simple login form with the predefined username and Password and I want to validate user input matches with username & password that I specified.

If the user enters wrong username or password I want to display an alert message. I tried to write possible conditions, but I am not getting the alert message even I entered the wrong password.

I am new to development and need your support to learn this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title> javascript-validataion </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="java.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascipt">


function check_info()

{

var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
var password=document.getElementById("password").value;

    if(username == "user1" && password == "123456")

      {
        alert("Login Successful");
        return false;
      }

      else
      { 
        alert("checkpassword"); 
      }

  } 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="submission.html" method="post"   onclick="return 
check_info()";>
     username:<input type="text" name="username"     id="username" /><br>
     </br>
     password:<input type="text" name="password"     id="password"/><br>
     </br>
     <input type="button" value="login" id="loginbtn"/>
</form>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest adding some code to the question

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title> javascript-validataion </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="java.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascipt">


function check_info()

{

var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
var password=document.getElementById("password").value;

    if(username == "user1" && password == "123456")
 
   {
  alert("Login Successful");
  return false;
   }
    
   else
   { 
  alert("checkpassword"); 
   }
   
  }

Comment: </script>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="submission.html" method="post" onclick="return check_info()";>
     username:<input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br>
  </br>
  password:<input type="text" name="password" id="password"/><br>
  </br>
  <input type="button" value="login" id="loginbtn"/>
</form>
</body>  
</html>

Comment: right .... that tells me about all I need to know ... please put code *in the question* is not the same as please put code *in a comment where it's impossible to read*

Comment: Hello venkat. Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please Refer [HOW TO ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . I can understand that you're new here but placing code in comment can not help you out instead consider editing your question and placing your code into it. :)

Comment: so what is wrong with the code you've tried - what is it doing wrong? (you haven't added ALL the html yet

Comment: Hello, I have added whole code here, please help me

Comment: note `<br>` is just `<br>` or `<br />`... not `<br></br>`

Comment: the `onclick` should be on the `input type=button`

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda X , I have modified but still my validation is not working if I enter wrong password.

Comment: pop message display on mouse click

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems in provided example:

1. Typo in `<script type="text/javascipt">` it should be `<script type="text/javascript">`
2. Use onclick in button `<input type="button" value="login" id="loginbtn" onclick="return check_info()"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this only with JS. You have to build a server side (e.g. with PHP or C#) page for querying the typed username using AJAX and then check the response. Also, you have to check the username existance on the confirmation before you update the new racord to the database for security reasons.

I suggest you to learn about AJAX and JQuery. If you are new, I suggest you to write simpler pages (e.g. a calculator or rock-paper-scissors game) for practise.

Comment: Then write an email to me so I could give some details: `solar.d.soul@gmail.com`